# How to deal with JSON column while using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm using a query similar to the below one, address is JSON TYPE.

```
SELECT id, name, MAX(salary), age, adress FROM test group by id, name, age
```

But getting below error:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type json
  Position: 152
```

I'm trying to get the data of a person who has the max salary for his age and I need to include adress filed which should be JSON

So, Is the there any way to achieve this or is this practically possible ?

Note:- `postgres db`

Comment: Perhaps `DISTINCT ON()` instead?

Comment: No, tried DISTINCT  just now. But same issue.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with `DISTINCT ON()` instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (age) id, name, salary, age, adress
FROM test
ORDER BY age, salary desc
```

The `DISTINCT ON (age)` will give you one row for each age. The one with the highest salary, as the `ORDER BY` decides.

Comment: Able to achieve with DISTINCT ON. Thank You Sir. You gave a hint to use DISTINCT ON in the comment section earlier, but I was not properly using DISTINCT so couldnot achieve. Anyways it worked now, Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in equality operator for type JSON but there *is* one for type JSONB. So you have a couple of immediate options:

- Change the type of column `adress` from JSON to JSONB (recommended). Your query will work then;
- Cast `adress` to type JSONB in the query

```sql
SELECT id, name, MAX(salary), age, adress::jsonb 
  FROM test 
 GROUP BY id, name, age, address::jsonb;
```

You can also [define](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xoper.html) an equality operator for type JSON yourself - well, rather as a drill than for production purposes.

Comment: Used the cast option. But its giving all the records. If  I remove address from select and group by then the functionality is fine.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. What if more than one person has the max salary for his age? Probably the query shall be very different.

Comment: I posted an example only here.  The actual issue was in a different scenario between different tables.